# How do I create a single PDF from multiple instances of a person's name in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Every Friday our students submit an electronic log of what they did in an extra-curricular activity using a Google Form. We want one PDF created each time a script is run. The problem is it creates a new PDF each time there is a new record in a sheet. We started to look at using a **pivot table** before creating the PDF, can't figure that part out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

```
var CLASSLIST = [];
var MAINLIST = [];

const MAINTAIN_GS = "1tFXqO0oKjm37P09Mi2jfYT-RML-G1dBr03qHPUzsT7w";
const MAINTAIN_SN = "Class & Teacher Email";
const STUDENT_FORM_SN="Form Responses 1";


const TEMPFOLDER_ID = "12Wzl_v_o-aJ_38P9YSshyQPTtGVXmsyH";
const TEMPLATE_DOC_ID = "1D0PBYPunBa63d0eC9b6IrzjAHmWzZVVJJM1zhhUVY3c";


function onOpen() {

  loadMainDetails();

 // Utilities.sleep(10000)

/*
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Send Email')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[0] ,'mainScript1')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[1] ,'mainScript2')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[2] ,'mainScript3')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[3] ,'mainScript4')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[4] ,'mainScript5')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[5] ,'mainScript6')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[6] ,'mainScript7')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[7] ,'mainScript8')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[8] ,'mainScript9')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[9] ,'mainScript10')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[10] ,'mainScript11')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[11] ,'mainScript12') 
  .addToUi(); */

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Send Email')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[0] ,'mainScript7I')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[1] ,'mainScript7P')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[2] ,'mainScript7S')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[3] ,'mainScript7W')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[4] ,'mainScript8I')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[5] ,'mainScript8P')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[6] ,'mainScript8S')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[7] ,'mainScript8W')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[8] ,'mainScript9I')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[9] ,'mainScript9P')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[10] ,'mainScript9S')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[11] ,'mainScript9W')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[12] ,'mainScript10A') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[13] ,'mainScript10B')
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[14] ,'mainScript10C') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[15] ,'mainScript10D') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[16] ,'mainScript10E') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[17] ,'mainScript11A') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[18] ,'mainScript11B') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[19] ,'mainScript11C') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[20] ,'mainScript11D') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[21] ,'mainScript11E') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[22] ,'mainScript12A') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[23] ,'mainScript12B') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[24] ,'mainScript12C') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[25] ,'mainScript12D') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[26] ,'mainScript12E') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[27] ,'mainScript13A') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[28] ,'mainScript13B') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[29] ,'mainScript13C') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[30] ,'mainScript13D') 
  .addItem(CLASSLIST[31] ,'mainScript13E') 
  .addItem("All", 'mainScriptAll')
  .addToUi();
   
 // menuEntries.push({name: "Generate PDF", functionName: "mainScript0"});

   // ss.addMenu("Email Teacher", menuEntries); 

  
  /* ss.addMenu("Send Email", menuEntries);

   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[0], functionName: "mainScript7I"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[1], functionName: "mainScript7P"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[2], functionName: "mainScript7S"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[3], functionName: "mainScript7W"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[4], functionName: "mainScript8I"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[5], functionName: "mainScript8P"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[6], functionName: "mainScript8S"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[7], functionName: "mainScript8W"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[8], functionName: "mainScript9I"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[9], functionName: "mainScript9S"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[10], functionName: "mainScript9P"});
   menuEntries.push({name: CLASSLIST[11], functionName: "mainScript9W"}); 
*/

   
}

function mainScript7I() {
    mainScriptByClass("A7", "C7","B7");   
}
function mainScript7P() {
    mainScriptByClass("A8","C8","B8"); 
}
function mainScript7S() {
    mainScriptByClass("A9","C9","B9");   
}
function mainScript7W() {
    mainScriptByClass("A10","C10","B10");  
}
function mainScript8I() {
    mainScriptByClass("A11", "C11","B11");  
}
function mainScript8P() {
    mainScriptByClass("A12", "C12","B12");  
}
function mainScript8S() {
    mainScriptByClass("A13", "C13","B13");  
}
function mainScript8W() {
    mainScriptByClass("A14", "C14","B14"); 
}
function mainScript9I() {
    mainScriptByClass("A15", "C15","B15");  
}
function mainScript9S() {
    mainScriptByClass("A16", "C16","B16"); 
}
function mainScript9P() {
    mainScriptByClass("A17", "C17","B17");  
}
function mainScript9W() {
    mainScriptByClass("A18", "C18","B18");  
}
function mainScript10A() {
    mainScriptByClass("A19", "C19","B19");  
}
function mainScript10B() {
    mainScriptByClass("A20", "C20","B20"); 
}
function mainScript10C() {
    mainScriptByClass("A21", "C21","B21");  
}
function mainScript10D() {
    mainScriptByClass("A22", "C22","B22");  
}
function mainScript10E() {
    mainScriptByClass("A23", "C23","B23");  
}
function mainScript11A() {
    mainScriptByClass("A24", "C24","B24");  
}
function mainScript11B() {
    mainScriptByClass("A25", "C25","B25"); 
}
function mainScript11C() {
    mainScriptByClass("A26", "C26","B26");  
}
function mainScript11D() {
    mainScriptByClass("A27", "C27","B27");  
}
function mainScript11E() {
    mainScriptByClass("A28", "C28","B28");  
}
function mainScript12A() {
    mainScriptByClass("A29", "C29","B29");  
}
function mainScript12B() {
    mainScriptByClass("A30", "C30","B30"); 
}
function mainScript12C() {
    mainScriptByClass("A31", "C31","B31");  
}
function mainScript12D() {
    mainScriptByClass("A32", "C32","B32"); 
}
function mainScript12E() {
    mainScriptByClass("A33", "C33","B33"); 
}
function mainScript13A() {
    mainScriptByClass("A34", "C34","B34");  
}
function mainScript13B() {
    mainScriptByClass("A35", "C35","B35"); 
}
function mainScript13C() {
    mainScriptByClass("A36", "C36","B36");  
}
function mainScript13D() {
    mainScriptByClass("A37", "C37","B37");  
}
function mainScript13E() {
    mainScriptByClass("A38", "C38","B38");  
}

function mainScriptAll() {

mainScript7I();
mainScript7P();
mainScript7S();
mainScript7W();
mainScript8I();
mainScript8P();
mainScript8S();
mainScript8W();
mainScript9I();
mainScript9P();
mainScript9S();
mainScript9W();
mainScript10A();
mainScript10B();
mainScript10C();
mainScript10D();
mainScript10E();
mainScript11A();
mainScript11B();
mainScript11C();
mainScript11D();
mainScript11E();
mainScript12A();
mainScript12B();
mainScript12C();
mainScript12D();
mainScript12E();
mainScript13A();
mainScript13B();
mainScript13C();
mainScript13D();
mainScript13E();


}


function mainScriptByClass(vClassCol, vEmailCol, vFolderCol) {



  if (vClassName != "ALL" ){  

    /* var TrueMaintain = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAINTAIN_GS).getSheetByName(MAINTAIN_SN);

    var vClassName = TrueMaintain.getRange(vClassCol).getValue();

    var emailID = TrueMaintain.getRange(vEmailCol).getValue();


    var urlID = TrueMaintain.getRange(vFolderCol).getValue(); */

    var vClassName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAINTAIN_GS).getSheetByName(MAINTAIN_SN).getRange(vClassCol).getValue();

    var emailID = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAINTAIN_GS).getSheetByName(MAINTAIN_SN).getRange(vEmailCol).getValue();
    Logger.log("emailID " + emailID)

    var urlID = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAINTAIN_GS).getSheetByName(MAINTAIN_SN).getRange(vFolderCol).getValue();

    generatePDFByClass(vClassName);

    Logger.log("URLID " + urlID);

    //generatePDFByClass(vClassName);


    var linkFromID = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" + urlID ;

    // GmailApp.sendEmail(emailID, "PDF Files for this week", "Hello these are the PDF results of the forms your student filled out:" + inkFromID);

    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailID, "PDF Files for this week", "Hello these are the PDF results of the forms your students filled out:" + linkFromID);

  } else {

      mainScript();

  }


}




function loadMainDetails () {

  var vClassName, vURL, vFTEmail;
  


 /* const ssMainFileID = "1SR2NFYOHZ2h2JANUoTsIZvFhLJ7RQc2ob--dU4IPNxk";
  const sMainFileSheet = "Class & Teacher Email"; */

  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MAINTAIN_GS);
  var ss = file.getSheetByName(MAINTAIN_SN);  

  /* Get Data from maintenance file */
  /* getRange (Row, Column, RowRange, ColumnRange) */
  vData = ss.getRange(7,1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, ss.getMaxColumns()).getDisplayValues();


  vData.forEach ( function (vRow) {
   // rowNum = rowNum + 1;

    if(vRow[0].length > 0 ){
     vClassName = vRow[0]; 
     vURL = vRow[1]; 
     vFTEmail = vRow[2];
     CLASSLIST.push(vClassName);
     //MAINLIST.push("{'className':'"+ vClassName + "','url':'" + vURL + "','ft':'" + vFTEmail +"'}")
     MAINLIST.push(vClassName + "," + vURL + "," + vFTEmail) 
    }
  });



}



function getURLByClass(sKeyClass) {

  var vURL = "";
  var mapList = [];

  for(var i in  MAINLIST){

    mapList =  MAINLIST[i].toString().split(",")
   if (sKeyClass == mapList[0] ) {
     vURL = mapList[1];
 
     break;
    }
  }
  
  return vURL;
}

function getFTMailByClass(sKeyClass) {

  var vEmail = "";
  var mapList = [];

  for(var i in  MAINLIST){
    mapList =  MAINLIST[i].toString().split(",")
   if (sKeyClass == mapList[0] ) {
     vEmail = mapList[2];

     break;
    }
  }
  
  return vEmail;
}


function generatePDFByClass(vClass){

  //Temp
  loadMainDetails();
  Logger.log("loadMainDetails"); 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var respSheet =ss.getSheetByName(STUDENT_FORM_SN);



  // Sorting by Class No
   var vRange = respSheet.getRange("A:G")
   vRange.sort ({column: 3, ascending: true} );

  var rowNum = 1;
  var vData = [];
  var vHeader  = [];
  var vSName,  vFTClass;
  var vPrevFTEmail = "",  vPrevFTClass = "" ;
  var vFTEmail = "";
  

  var headerNum = 0;

  var maxColumn = respSheet.getMaxColumns();

   Logger.log("maxColumn" +  maxColumn);
  
  /* Get Headers to apply in template as Q */
  vHeader = respSheet.getRange(1,1,1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();

  /* Get Data to apply in in template as A */
   Logger.log("Header" + vHeader);
  /* getRange (Row, Column, RowRange, ColumnRange) */
  vData = respSheet.getRange(2,1, respSheet.getLastRow() - 1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();

  Logger.log("Data " + vData);

 
   
  /* Response inputs  */
  vData.forEach ( function (vRow) {
    rowNum = rowNum + 1;

      //if(vRow[3] == vClass){
        if(vRow[2] == vClass){
        vSName = vRow[1]; 
        vFTClass = vRow[2];
          Logger.log("vFTClass " + vFTClass);
        
      //  vFTClass = vRow[3];

        vPrevFTEmail = vFTEmail;

            // Setup FT Email at Column AA for Reference.
        //respSheet.getRange("AA" + rowNum).setValue(vFTEmail);

        // Start Column
        var vStartColumn = 1

        // Student Line for generate PDF and Email
        sData = respSheet.getRange(rowNum,vStartColumn, 1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();
       // var nPdfFile = createBulkPDF(vHeader, sData, vSName, vFTClass);


        createBulkPDF(vHeader, sData, vSName, vFTClass);
        vPrevFTClass = vFTClass;
    }
   
  });

}


function mainScript(){

  //Temp
  loadMainDetails(); 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var respSheet =ss.getSheetByName(STUDENT_FORM_SN);

  // Sorting by Class No
  var vRange = respSheet.getRange("A:G")
  vRange.sort ({column: 3, ascending: true});

  var rowNum = 1;
  var vData = [];
  var vHeader  = [];
  var vSName,  vFTClass;
  var vPrevFTEmail = "",  vPrevFTClass = "" ;
  var vFTEmail = "";
  

  var headerNum = 0;

  var maxColumn = respSheet.getMaxColumns()
  
  /* Get Headers to apply in template as Q */
  vHeader = respSheet.getRange(1,1,1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();


  /* Get Data to apply in in template as A */
  /* getRange (Row, Column, RowRange, ColumnRange) */
  vData = respSheet.getRange(2,1, respSheet.getLastRow() - 1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();

 
   
  /* Response inputs  */
  vData.forEach ( function (vRow) {
    rowNum = rowNum + 1;

    if(vRow[0].length > 0 ){
     vSName = vRow[1]; 
     
     vFTClass = vRow[3];

     vPrevFTEmail = vFTEmail;
     
   
     vFTEmail =  getFTMailByClass(vFTClass);


     
     /*  Send email by Grouping */
    if (vPrevFTClass != "" && vFTClass != vPrevFTClass) {
      sendRespMail(vPrevFTEmail, vPrevFTClass);
     // vPrevFTClass = vFTClass;

  
    //  vAllPDF.splice(0, vAllPDF.length) 
    }

    }

    

    // Setup FT Email at Column AA for Reference.
    //respSheet.getRange("AA" + rowNum).setValue(vFTEmail);

    // Start Column
    var vStartColumn = 1

    // Student Line for generate PDF and Email
    sData = respSheet.getRange(rowNum,vStartColumn, 1, maxColumn).getDisplayValues();
    //var nPdfFile = createBulkPDF(vHeader, sData, vSName, vFTClass);

    createBulkPDF(vHeader, sData, vSName, vFTClass);
    vPrevFTClass = vFTClass;

 
    //vAllPDF.push(nPdfFile);

  });


  /* Last Email Group */
  //if (vFTClass != vPrevFTClass) {
     // sendRespMail(vFTEmail, vFTClass);
      sendRespMail(vFTEmail,vFTClass )
    
 
  //}
  
}

function sendRespMail(email, className){

  var url_link = getURLByClass(className);

   var message = "Hello, this is a URL fpr group of PDFs containing the Data of your class (" + className + ")";
   message = message + "stduents who filled out the Google Form.\n";
   message = message + "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" + url_link;
 
  var emailTo = email;
  var subject = "Forms filled out this Friday";
  var html = message;




  if( emailTo != "") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,html,"" ); 
  }


}


function sendRespMailforAttachment(email,  pdfFiles){

   var message = "Hello, this is a group of PDFs containing the Data of your class  ";
   message = message + "stduents who filled out the Google Form."
 
  var emailTo = email;
  var subject = "Forms filled out this Friday";
  var html = message;


  if( emailTo != "") {
  //  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,html,{ attachments: pdfFiles }  ); 
  }


}


function createBulkPDF(pHeader, pData, pSName, pClass){

Logger.log("createBulkPDF1");


  var rowNum = 2;

  var allPDF = [];
 
  var vTemplateDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_DOC_ID);
  var vTempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TEMPFOLDER_ID);


  var tempFile = vTemplateDocFile.makeCopy(vTempFolder);
  var tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  var body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  // Fill in Header for A  { }
  var hRowNum = 1;
  pHeader.forEach ( function (hRow) {
    hRowNum = hRowNum + 1;
   
    for (var i = 1; i < hRow.length; i++){
     body.replaceText("{Q" + i + "}", hRow[i] ); 

    }
  });
Logger.log("createBulkPDF2");
     // Fill in Inputs for Q { } 
  var sRowNum = 1;
  pData.forEach ( function (sRow) {
    sRowNum = sRowNum + 1;
     for (var i = 1; i < sRow.length; i++){
     body.replaceText("{A" + i + "}", sRow[i] ); 

    }
  });

  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  var vPdfContentBlob = tempDocFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var pdfName = pSName+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+8"," HH:mm:ss")+".pdf";
  
  var classFolderID = getURLByClass(pClass);
  var vPdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(classFolderID);
  var pdfRpt=vPdfFolder.createFile(vPdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
 // var pdfRpt=vPdfFolder.createFile(vPdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);

  DriveApp.getFileById(tempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);

Logger.log("createBulkPDF3");
  return pdfRpt;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `We want one PDF created each time a script is run. The problem is it creates a new PDF each time there is a new record in a sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your issue and your goal?

Comment: Your English is great by the way!

Students will enter the raw data in a Google Form, which points to a Google Sheet.

Let's say the spreadsheet looks like this:

Bob | Journal | 24/07/21 | 30 minutes
Bob | Brief | 31/07/21 | 60 minutes
Bob | Creation | 17/08/21 | 60 minutes

We want one PDF that 'merges' all instances of 'Bob' into one PDF. At the moment, a new PDF is created for each instance (of Bob), so we end up with 3 PDFs in this case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I might be able to understand your goal from your replying. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your script. So now I cannot propose an answer. I apologize for this. When I could correctly understand your script, I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you already have a Sheet with the data and a separate function to convert it to a PDF, therefore you only need to refine the table so it only shows a particular student. Based on your comment, I guess that the table looks like this:

[image: Initial step]

First of all I strongly recommend you to use a [filter table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) instead of a [pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900), because it will fit better to your goal and you can code it pretty easily. You can include my example below into your project as is, you would only need to change the student name from `Irène` to whatever your need.

```js
function studentFilter() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  sheet.getRange(data).createFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo('Irène')
    .build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
};
```

That code would use the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class of Apps Script to open the Sheet and get its range. After that it would create a filter table using the [`.createFilter()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter) method and the [`FilterCriteriaBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder) class. After both the filter table and its criteria is created, it just applies the criteria to the table. This would be the end result on the previous example:

[image: Final step]

At this point the Sheet already looks like your goal, so you only need to follow your usual workflow and call the printing PDF function.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll let you know how it goes.